# Wave equation for lie groups

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In local coordinates what will be the wave equations for compact lie groups ? The eqation is 
$$\partial^2_tu-a(t)Lu=f$$

where L is the laplacian in G. What is this in local coordinates?

Comment: Edited your question to make the $\LaTeX$ of the equation clear. Remember your "$$" signs!   Cheers!

Comment: I assume $\delta_t^2 u = \partial^2 u / \partial t^2$.  Correct?

Comment: yes. correct. It is \partial^2u/\partial t^2.

Comment: By the way, you might try and remember to surround your $\LaTeX$ with "\$" signs, thusly:  "\$\LaTeX\$"; it's almost unreadable otherwise!  If you look at other questions and answers in "edit" mode, you can see how it's done!  Cheers!